# Why won't this ctypes code work with Python 3.3 but will work with Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-7, ctypes

So I'm trying to make a Python 3.3 program to change the Windows desktop background using the ctypes module. I've tested the following code in Python 2.7, and it worked perfectly. But it just won't work with Python 3.3! I'm using Windows 7. Here's the code:

```
import ctypes
SPI_SETDESKTOPWALLPAPER=20
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKTOPWALLPAPER, 0,"C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Penguins.jpg", 3)
```

Comment: I'm attempting to figure out why I got voted down. I provided code and am merely asking for an explanation. There is nothing weak about the question.

Comment: Forget downvotes, did you try `SystemParametersInfoW`

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thanks! And sorry! I started my comment before you started yours.

Comment: "I'm attempting to figure out why I got voted down" --> Tagging non-C posts as [C] attracts down votes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`SystemParametersInfoA` requires a 8-bit ANSI encoded input string as a parameter, which is known as `mbcs` encoding in [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/unicode.html#encodings).

You will have to use `SystemParametersInfoW` in python3. This is because `SystemParametersInfoW` takes in a UTF-16 wide string (which is `wchar_t *` in C) and the `ctypes` library automatically converts this passed unicode argument into `c_wchar_p`.

Refer the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ctypes.html#accessing-functions-from-loaded-dlls) for more details.