# Why does changing my desktop through python result in a red wallpaper?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, wallpaper

I created a simple script that gets the hottest post on /r/wallpapers, downloads it to a directory, and is supposed to set it as my Windows 10 wallpaper.

However, every time I run the script my wallpaper turns red. If I were to right click on my downloaded image and set it as my wallpaper, it works fine.

```
import praw
import urllib.request
import os
import ctypes

def main():
    change_wallpaper(get_image())

def change_wallpaper(url):
    SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
    directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "\\bin\\" + 'image.jpg'
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,directory)

    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, directory, 0)


def get_image():
    reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='id', client_secret='secret', user_agent='app')
    get_hottest = reddit.subreddit('wallpapers').hot(limit=1)

    for post in get_hottest:
        url = post.url
        title = post.title
        author = post.author
    return url
main()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a background changer in python with ctypes, not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715895/creating-a-background-changer-in-python-with-ctypes-not-working) → use `SystemParametersInfoW`.

Comment: It does work! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

user mkrieger1 suggested using `SystemParametersInfoW` instead of `SystemParametersInfoA` and it works now!